# Choosing right properties of a model class depending on the locale settings?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, realm

Say, I have a model (for a Realm db):

```
class Country: Object {
  dynamic var id = ""
  dynamic var nameRu = ""
  dynamic var nameEn = ""
}
```

Somewhere in the code I'm displaying the name of a country like this:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = countries[indexPath.row].nameRu
```

So, how can I automatically display `nameRu` or `nameEn` depending on the locale settings? Is there a "smart" way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could something like the following work?

```
let country = countries[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = country["name\(localization)"]
```

where `localization` is either `En` or `Ru`?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the standard iOS localization approach. This approach assumes your base localization is English so "Country::name" is "Russia" which will act as the 'key' to the Localizable.strings.

1. Your country object doesn't need to hold all the translations; thus simplify to:

   ```
   class Country: Object {
           dynamic var id = ""
           dynamic var name = ""
   }
   ```
2. Create a Localizable.strings file (for ru-RU)

   ```
   /* 
           Localizable.strings (ru-RU)
   */
   "Russia" = "Россия"
   "Germany" = "Германия"

   /* 
           Localizable.strings (en-US)
           (optional)
   */
   "Russia" = "Russia"
   "Germany" = "Germany"
   ```
3. Invoke using:

   ```
   cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString(countries[indexPath.row].name, comment: "Country name  that will translate based on iOS region preference in Settings > General > Language & Region")
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option 'cause the data is dynamic and the example with Country is simplified. In the real life there are other types of data with translations. And storing localized strings for dynamic data is unacceptable. I do this kind of stuff that you wrote about but for static data from UI controls labels, etc.